# Reactive Vue Router object by wrapping in ref() not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have an application where I would like to print the location of the user similar to a breadcrumb. I have a component that I add at the application level and expect it to update with current value or the `router.currentRoute` object. However it doesn't seem to be updating as expected.

I'm using the Vue2 Composition api plugin and am trying hard to keep it in a decent state that will make migrating to Vue3 much easier once I'm able. This means I'd like to avoid using the `context.$route` object that's available. My attempt currently imports the router directly and wraps the `currentRoute` object in a `ref()` but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-rosalind-byc5x?file=/src/components/CurrentLocation.vue) with an application that shows the issue. I have a home page and two additional pages. The text that reads 'Your current location is: Home` should change to the name of the other pages when navigating there, however it does not change at all.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Your current location is: {{ location.name }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
import router from "@/router";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Page1",
  setup() {
    const location = ref(router.currentRoute);

    return { location };
  },
});
</script>
```

Please let me know if there is a way to do this the way I'd like. If it's not possible I'll just bite the bullet and use `context.$route` and deal with the larger refactoring when I migrate to Vue3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reactive()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive) on the `router` instance, and then [`toRef()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#toref) on that to get  `currentRoute`:

```js
import { defineComponent, reactive, toRef } from '@vue/composition-api'
import router from '@/router'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const location = toRef(reactive(router), 'currentRoute')
    return { location }
  }
})
```

[Vue 2 demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactive-routercurrentroute-in-vue-2-composition-api-r6obx?file=/src/components/CurrentLocation.vue:274-336)

You'll probably migrate this in Vue 3 anyway because the [next version of Vue Router already has different semantics for the Composition API](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#accessing-the-router-and-current-route-inside-setup). You could simply use [`useRoute()`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#useroute) from Vue Router 4 in Vue 3:

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const location = useRoute()
    return { location }
  }
})
```

[Vue 3 demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactive-routercurrentroute-in-vue-3-composition-api-sozrt?file=/src/components/CurrentLocation.vue:248-281)

Comment: Is useRoute() from vue router 4 reactive? Because we know useRouter().currentRoute is not reactive. What is the difference between  useRoute() and useRouter().currentRoute? For example both of them contains meta, useRouter().currentRoute.value.meta vs useRoute().meta